# Regexp::Assemble and Infinite loop

Tags: regex, perl, cpan

I have the following code could someone explain why this code enter infinite loop and how i can capture the matched patterns .

```
my $dis = (ff =>  'dfsdf2'
           yy => 'xx');

my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new->track(1)->add(keys %dis);

my $data='blah blah ff dfsf yy';

while( $ra->match($data) ) {
        my $res = $ra->matched;
      print $res;
    }
```

I am using v5.18.0 strawberry and the updated Regexp::Assemble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regexp::Assemble doesn't have any built-in support for iteration like that.  You'd have to do:

```
use 5.010;
my $re = $ra->re;
while ( $data =~ /$re/g ) {
    my $res = $ra->source($^R);
    print $res;
}
```